# Slugs in symfony

Tags: php, symfony1

I have a problem with slugs in symfony. I defined the slug fields with the last_name and first_name fields but when I load the fixtures, the slug for each fixture is created based on the title field of the table and not based on my defined fields. do you know why this could happen?

```
Faculty: 
  tableName: faculty
  inheritance: 
    extends: SvaGeneric 
    type: concrete 
  columns: 
    instructor_id: { type: string(20) } 
    first_name: { type: string(255), notnull: true } 
    last_name: { type: string(255), notnull: true } 
    title: { type: string(80) } 
  actAs: 
    Sluggable: 
      unique: true 
      fields: [last_name,first_name] 
      canUpdate: true
```

Comment: Show us the schema of that table.

Comment: Please, copy and paste the portion of schema.yml where you defined this.

Comment: Symfony 1.4 and the schema of the table is the following: 
Faculty:
  tableName: faculty
  inheritance:
    extends: SvaGeneric
    type: concrete
  columns:
    instructor_id: { type: string(20) }
    first_name: { type: string(255), notnull: true }
    last_name: { type: string(255), notnull: true }
    title: { type: string(80) }
  actAs: 
    Sluggable:
      unique: true
      fields: [last_name,first_name]
      canUpdate: true

Comment: As you can see, the slug fields are defined, but when I rebuild the schema, it always create the fixtures with the title field as the sluggable field

Comment: @3s73ban keep in mind that you can edit your questions to include additional details. I edited it in for you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your definition looks like:

```
# config/doctrine/schema.yml
JobeetCategory:
  actAs:
    Timestampable: ~
    Sluggable:
      fields: [name]
  columns:
    first_name:
      type: string(255)
      notnull:  true
    last_name: {type: string(255), notnull:true }
```

So set the fields the right way:
    Sluggable: { fields: [first_name,last_name],  }

Maybe you check if you need "uniqueBy" or a custom behaviour for multi-column slugs.